# Hi-Tech C Compiler: #define: "taking the address of this object is illegal"

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, pic, hi-tech-c

I'm trying to compile code for a PIC16F77 microcontroller using the Hi-Tech C compiler.

The code below gives an error on the last line in the snippet below. The errors are:

```
Error   [195] C:\...\.c; 8.1 expression syntax
Error   [201] C:\...\.c; 8.8 taking the address of this object is illegal
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the following:

```
#define TEST1       0x01;
#define TEST2       0x80;
#define TEST3       (TEST1 | TEST2)

// in main():
ADCON0 = TEST1; // works
ADCON0 = TEST2; // works
ADCON0 = TEST3; // compile error
```

(`ADCON0` is the 8-bit register which has flags for controlling the ADC.)

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: Check you semi-colons...

Comment: And debug this sort of thing with the `-E` flag to your C compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons from your defines of `TEST1` and `TEST2`, cause with them, `TEST3` expands to `(0x01; | 0x80;)`

Comment: Indeed.  However, this question is therefore best dealt with via the new "simple typographical error" close reason (plus a comment)...

Comment: Oh, a new close reason. Cool!

Comment: It turns out I had another expression lurking with an `=` assignment, which some how I missed. It's too early in the morning clearly